# How to save intermidiate results on Amazon EC2 when spot instance used?

Tags: amazon-ec2, storage

I do some scientific calculations and I have some intermidiate results on each iteration, so I think I can use spot instance reduce cost of processing.

How can I save intermidiate results on each iteration?

How can I automatically rerun instance from last checkpoint when it's terminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the spot price of an Amazon EC2 instance rises above your bid price, your Amazon EC2 instance is terminated. A **2-minute notice** is provided via the metadata interface. You can use this notice as a trigger for saving your work, or you could simply save work at regular intervals regardless of the notice period.

Do not save your work "locally", since the Amazon EBS volumes will either be deleted (eg boot volume) or disconnected (eg data volumes). I would recommend that you save your work in a persistent datastore, such as a database or Amazon S3.

One option would be to save files to your local disk, but use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to copy the files to Amazon S3 using the `aws s3 sync` command.

Then, if you have configured a persistent spot instance, simply copy the files from Amazon S3 when the new Amazon EC2 spot instance is started.

See:

- [Spot Instance Interruptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html)